# Weird AdMob javascript errors over wifi after 1-2 minutes

Tags: javascript, android, admob, wifi, 3g

My problem is when I'm using wifi and I'm trying to load ads on Android app i get some javascript errors (scroll down a bit for log). If i haven't used my tablet for about some hours and connect to wifi i can see the ads for 1-2 minutes, then the error will show up once again. If my friend creates wifi with his 3g connection ads are just fine. Can anyone help me out? Its just with my tablet device

**DEVICE INFO**

> build.board: EBM7000NBD
>
> build.bootloader: unknown
>
> build.brand: MID
>
> build.cpu_abi: armeabi-v7a
>
> build.cpu_abi2: armeabi
>
> build.device: EBM7000NBD
>
> build.display: V1.0.5.JRO03C.user.root.20131223
>
> build.fingerprint:
>   MID/EBM7000NBD/EBM7000NBD:4.1.1/JRO03C/eng.root.20131223.104152:user/release-keys
>
> build.hardware: amlogic
>
> build.host: xn-desktop
>
> build.id: JRO03C
>
> build.manufacturer: YIFANG
>
> build.model: NX007HD8G
>
> build.product: EBM7000NBD
>
> build.radio: unknown
>
> build.serial: unknown
>
> build.tags: release-keys
>
> build.time: 1387766643000
>
> build.type: user
>
> build.user: root
>
> version.codename: REL
>
> version.incremental: eng.root.20131223.104152
>
> version.release: 4.1.1
>
> version.sdk_int: 16

**LOGCAT**

```
10-06 17:00:14.411 I/Ads     (7302): Starting ad request.

10-06 17:00:14.411 I/Ads     (7302): Use 
AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("63EDFD38B0AC9B029479F0456399E7C9") to get test ads on this device.

10-06 17:00:14.671 E/Ads     (3742): JS: <error> 
(https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.js:111)

10-06 17:00:14.671 E/Web Console(3742): <error> at https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.js:111

10-06 17:00:14.681 E/Ads     (3742): JS: <error> (null:1)

10-06 17:00:14.681 E/Web Console(3742): <error> at null:1

10-06 17:00:15.061 D/dalvikvm(7302): GC_CONCURRENT freed 314K, 54% free 7081K/15367K, paused 11ms+4ms, total 41ms

10-06 17:00:15.331 I/wpa_supplicant(3902): [CTRL_IFACE]wlan0: SIGNAL_POLL

10-06 17:00:18.341 I/wpa_supplicant(3902): [CTRL_IFACE]wlan0: SIGNAL_POLL

10-06 17:00:18.831 W/ActivityManager(3425): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{424d34b0 com.gsoft.appinstall/.main}

10-06 17:00:19.691 V/TabletStatusBar(3499): setLightsOn(true)

10-06 17:00:21.341 I/wpa_supplicant(3902): [CTRL_IFACE]wlan0: SIGNAL_POLL

10-06 17:00:22.291 D/audio_hw_primary(2374): out_standby(0x43e19238)

10-06 17:00:22.291 D/audio_hw_primary(2374): do_output_standby(0x43e19238)

10-06 17:00:22.291 V/audio_hw_primary(2374): ~~~~ do_output_standby()....  call pcm_close() ##########8

10-06 17:00:22.711 D/dalvikvm(7325): GC_CONCURRENT freed 616K, 28% free 9079K/12551K, paused 
14ms+6ms, total 106ms

10-06 17:00:22.711 D/dalvikvm(7325): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 81ms

10-06 17:00:22.831 D/dalvikvm(7325): GC_CONCURRENT freed 61K, 21% free 10006K/12551K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 76ms

10-06 17:00:22.841 D/dalvikvm(7325): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 68ms

10-06 17:00:24.351 I/wpa_supplicant(3902): [CTRL_IFACE]wlan0: SIGNAL_POLL

10-06 17:00:24.611 W/Ads     (7302): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0

10-06 17:00:24.621 W/Ads     (7302): Failed to load ad: 0
```

Comment: Could it be that your code is trying to access the internet at times and is unable to do so, thus generating errors? Post your code so that we can have a look at what is going on.

Comment: Its not really my code, just copy paste from AdMob.
The problem must be in my device because with other phones/tablets its working fine, only my tablet causing drama with wifi.

Comment: I would like to add to my pervious comment that its also happening with any other app and even the famous Hill Climb Racing, moPub, a bit different debug text but still aint showing ads over wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I would break this out into a two  of discrete tests that will help narrow or solve your issue.

**Step 1**: Observe behavior on WIFI only devices vs. 3-4G cellular. If your code is working fine on cellular devises and behaving belligerently on WIFI, then it could be a network issue associated with signal strength or access. If it is the other way around it could still be a networking issue. You may need to make adjustments to your code involving network management. See [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html) for more information.

**Step 2**: Compare your logs on devices that are working properly with the one that is failing and see what the differences will tell you.